# I can't display the result of query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't display my query from database to CodeIgniter.

My table has "`id`, `description`, `date_stamp`". I just want to get only the `date_stamp`.

Here is my code:

Model

```
public function get_holidays()
{
    $this->db->select('date_stamp');
    $this->db->from('holidays');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $query->row();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data = "";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Controller:

```
    $holidays = $this->emp->get_holidays();
    //the result should be like this
    //$holidays=array("2013-09-20","2013-09-23", "2013-09-25");
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        // 
         echo $holiday['date_stamp'];
    }
```

Comment: i also receive a message "Method name must be a string"

Comment: Did you load the `model` ?

Comment: oh yes. from the top. i added this. $this->load->model('mdl_employee','emp');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Model

```
  public function get_holidays()
  {
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('date_stamp');
    $this->db->from('holidays');
     $query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {

        $data[]=$row->date_stamp; //changed here
       // array_push($data, $row->date_stamp); 

    }
}
else
{
    $data = array();
}
return $data;
}
```

Updated Controller

```
    $this->load->model('holiday_model');

    $holidays = $this->emp->get_holidays();
    //the result should be like this
    //$holidays=array("2013-09-20","2013-09-23", "2013-09-25");


    if($holidays) { //checking $holiday 
      foreach($holidays as $holiday){
         echo $holiday; //changed here
     }
    } else {
        echo 'No Holiday Found; //changed here
    }
```

Now it will work fine

Comment: `array_push($data, $row->date_stamp);` unnecessary and expensive than `$data[]=$row->date_stamp`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, inside `foreach ($query->result() as $row)` loop

```
$data[] = $query->row();
```

should be

```
$data[] = $row;
```

or, just return the result `return $query->result()` from the model and do the loop in the controller, because you are again doing same thing. So, you can do in your `model` instead

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
return false;
```

Then, in your `controller` you may do

```
$holidays = $this->emp->get_holidays();
if($holidays) {
    // do the loop or whatever you want
}
```

But, make sure to `echo` the result in `view`, hope you do so, also, don't forget to load the `model`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually print the value from model in view while controller is where I navigate the page to. Well, in model:

```
public function get_holidays()
{
    $this->db->select('date_stamp');
    $this->db->from('holidays');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

and in view:

```
$this->load->model('holiday_model');
$holidays = $this->holiday_model->get_holidays();

foreach( $holidays->result AS $items ) 
{
    echo $item->date_stamp;
}
```